# java eclipse: failed to load nxt usb comm driver

Tags: java, nxt

I have problems with java eclipse indigo, the plugin lejos for the nxt brick.
The problem is that i have installed the hole software/drivers which i need to program it.

operating system: windows 7

---

But the console say following:

```
Linking ...
Program has been linked successfully
Uploading ...
leJOS NXJ> Error: Failed to load USB comms driver.
leJOS NXJ> Caused by lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommException: Cannot load NXTComm driver
leJOS NXJ>  at lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommFactory.newNXTCommInstance(NXTCommFactory.java:110)
leJOS NXJ> Caused by lejos.internal.jni.JNIException: library jfantom.dll was not       found in C:\Program Files (x86)\leJOS NXJ\lib\pc\native, architecture    windows/x86_64
leJOS NXJ>  at lejos.internal.jni.JNILoader.loadLibrary(JNILoader.java:127)
Native Library intelbth_x64 not available
Native Library bluecove_x64 not available
leJOS NXJ> Error: Exception connecting to NXT.
leJOS NXJ> Caused by lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommException: Open of NXT_PETER failed.
leJOS NXJ>  at lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommBluecove.open(NXTCommBluecove.java:136)
leJOS NXJ> Caused by javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove libraries not available
leJOS NXJ>  at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.createDetectorOnWindows(BlueCoveImpl.java:896)
leJOS NXJ> Failed to connect to any NXT
No NXT found - is it switched on and plugged in (for USB)?
uploading the program failed with exit status 1
```

---

The LeJOS_HOME is configured and the jfantom.dll is in the folder...
and in the device-manager is the robo stated.

please help me!
thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should use all 32bits softwares.

Since lego only supports 32bit's usb driver, it can't locate the write version driver to upload programs into you NXT when you use 64bit's eclipse.

All 32bit's softwares include 32bit jdk and 32bit eclipse.