# Unable to Load LeJOS NXT Comm Driver

Tags: nxt, lejos-nxj

I have been trying to generate an interface with my NXT robot, using the LeJOS libraries. When I run the code I get the following error printed to the console:

`lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommException: Cannot load NXTComm driver
    at lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommFactory.newNXTCommInstance(NXTCommFactory.java:110)
    at lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommFactory.createNXTComm(NXTCommFactory.java:91)
    at com.thirteenbit.prasController.PrasController.initConnection(PrasController.java:24)
    at com.thirteenbit.prasController.PrasController.<init>(PrasController.java:17)
    at com.thirteenbit.prasController.PrasController$1.run(PrasController.java:42)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: lejos.internal.jni.JNIException: cannot load library /Users/Andrew/Desktop/Dropbox/Eclipse Files/leJOS_NXJ_0.9.1beta-3/lib/pc/native/macosx/libjfantom.jnilib, architecture macosx/x86_64
    at lejos.internal.jni.JNILoader.loadLibrary(JNILoader.java:121)
    at lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommFantom.initialize0(NXTCommFantom.java:96)
    at lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommFantom.initialize(NXTCommFantom.java:103)
    at lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommFactory.newNXTCommInstance(NXTCommFactory.java:103)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/Andrew/Desktop/Dropbox/Eclipse Files/leJOS_NXJ_0.9.1beta-3/lib/pc/native/macosx/libjfantom.jnilib:  no suitable image found.  Did find:  /Users/Andrew/Desktop/Dropbox/Eclipse Files/leJOS_NXJ_0.9.1beta-3/lib/pc/native/macosx/libjfantom.jnilib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1020)
    at lejos.internal.jni.JNILoader.loadLibrary(JNILoader.java:111)
    ... 21 more`

I believe that this is identical to the problem found in [java eclipse: failed to load nxt usb comm driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166040/java-eclipse-failed-to-load-nxt-usb-comm-driver), and I installed eclipse 32-Bit version and I still am getting the same error, the one above. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Should I try to reinstall the driver?

Answer (score 1):

Because I can't post comments due to my reputation (I'm new), an answer:
You should make sure you have:
- x86 [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) (Java Development Kit), click: jdk-7u21-windows-i586.exe
- Lego fantom [drivers](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/support/files/Driver.aspx) , click: Fantom Driver 1.1.3
and as you already mentioned a 32-Bit version of Eclipse

Comment: I am running Mac and the x86 version isn't in that list. There is a x64 version, though. I'm sorry I don't have much experience on things like this. If you have the time I would love a full description. Thanks.

Comment: I have no knowledge at all of mac's and how to set up Java on it, so I'll try:

Comment: First you need to (re)install the Fantom Driver 1.1.3 as mentioned earlier. I see there's no x86 JDK version for Mac, so the x64 version cannot be your problem. In order to be able to help you, I first need to know which java-related programmes you've already installed and whether you've set up the environment variables (so lejos knows the directories of the JDK and the like).

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try that. Do you know anything about the LeJOS android bluetooth support? Thanks again! @Rob

Comment: Ok, please report back the results. Yes, I've succesfully set up bluetooth communication between a NXT running LeJOS and a phone running Android a while ago. If you don't know where to start, just by reading all available information on Stackoverflow about how to set up a connection, I managed to get it working myself.